# spring boot active mq get count of active subscribers for a given topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

Before sending a message for a topic I want to know if there are any active subscribers for that topic. In case of no active subscribers I don't have to send the message.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to avoid that? As a producer, you shouldn't care if someone listens to that topic.

Comment: @CodeMatrix So if a subscriber joins after a message has been enqueued will it receive the message every time.

Comment: By forcing the producer to care about the consumer(s) you're breaking one of the central tenets for messaging systems which is that producers and consumers should be logically separated and shouldn't care about each other. This tenet exists to simplify application design and to increase application scalability.

Answer (score 2):

A JMS Topic does not retain messages if there are no active subscribers unless they are durable subscriptions in which case they've specifically asked for receipt of messages sent to the Topic while offline.  You should not concern yourself as a sender if there are consumers on a Topic or not as that is not how decoupled messaging is designed.

Since you've chosen a Topic you should accept that messages sent while no subscribers are active will be dropped and if you want retention either use a durable subscription or decide that perhaps a Queue is more appropriate mechanism for your use case.